# How to achive this random width grid view in flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-getx

[image]These texts will come from rest API. I need to show these in a bottom sheet. But I am not supposed to keep the width fix. Instead, the container's width will depend on text's length. How to make this in flutter?

```
GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  itemCount: controller.data.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                  ),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Obx(() => controller.fakeObs.isTrue
                        ? InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              controller.commentTap(
                                  text: "${controller.data[index]}");
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              child: Text("${controller.data[index]}"),
                            ),
                          )
                        : Container());
                  },
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a widget that surves my purpose. Sharing here

```
Wrap(
                    spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
                    runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int index = 0;
                          index < controller.data.length;
                          index++)
                        FilterChip(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          elevation: 5,
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          label: Text(
                            "${controller.data[index]}",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontWeight: AppTextStyle.mediumFont,
                                color: AppColors.TextGrey),
                          ),
                          onSelected: (bool value) {
                            print(
                                "DATA IS ${controller.data[index]} $value");
                          },
                        )
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the correct answer but helpful.. you can do this
width: controller. data[index]. length * 10 + 20

in this 10 can be any number however you want to set the width and 20 is the horizontal padding.. 10 from left, 10 from right.

Comment: already tried something similar. but not working. thank you for suggestion. Appreciate it